# YYYYMMDD to Date String combined with multiple date criteria

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I think the problem I have having seems to be a combination of two factors hence my combining in the Title.

I have two fields in a table that are YYYYMMDD in a text format.

I am attempting to create a query that will first convert these two columns into a date format as mm/yy/yyyy (the data will later be exported to excel) as well as set parameterised criteria in both fields.

So for example I want to only see data where the efffrom field is less than an input date and also where the effto fields is greater than another input date.

I've tried using DateValue and cdate but I seem to not be getting very far. I can handle the date part correctly but when I try to have the second criteria (not that the first worked correctly) I get the 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression' error.

I'm not sure if there is anything I can provide that would help assist me but I appreciate any solution.

Comment: Have you considered just storing your dates in the date format? Then deal with any formatting in your forms/excel?

Comment: Briefly. The reason I am building this process is to automate report creation for customers. My current approach is spit out the file as required and send it. This one requires the US date format and I'd like the solution to not require any editing post export.

Comment: You should still store the date as a date, then if you want to format it in SQL just use `Format`, e.g. `FORMAT([Date], "MM/dd/yyyy") AS FormattedDate`

Comment: Can you expand on that a little? How do I store the YYYYMMDD as a date? I've been using Datevalue with left, right and mid functions. It's using this with the two date criteria that I want to input that throws up the error.

Answer (score 0):

Let this VBA code be your guide:

```
Public Function DateFromYYYYMMDD(ymdText)
    If VarType(ymdText) <> vbString Then
        ymdText = CStr(ymdText)
    End If
    If Len(ymdText) <> 8 Then
        Err.Raise 5
    End If
    DateFromYYYYMMDD = CDate(Left(ymdText, 4) + "-" _
        + Mid(ymdText, 5, 2) _
        + "-" + Right(ymdText, 2))
End Function
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your field from Text to Date/Time. To do this you first need to add a new column, add the converted values to it, then remove the old column, and rename the new column. To do this I started with a table `Table1`:

[image]

Then added some values to the text field in the format yyyyMMdd:

[image]

The next step is to add a new column with the data type `Date/Time`:

[image]

Then run the following SQL to update your new column to the corresponding date:

```
UPDATE  Table1
SET     DateFieldCopy = DATESERIAL(LEFT(DateField,4), MID(DateField,5,2), RIGHT(DateField,2));
```

Finally, you can delete your old column, and rename your new column:

[image]

Now that you have the column in the correct format you can use the format function to get the data in any format you want. The following query should give the format you want:

```
SELECT  ID, DateField, FORMAT([DateField], "MM/dd/yyyy") AS FormattedDate
FROM    Table1;
```

[image]

Comment: I am currently working in a database that is linked to the source database which cannot be changed. As such I am using a query against the linked table.


My query expression is as per the below. I get the correct date but it doesn't seem to work with paramter criteria against the 2. Is the below correct?


EFFFROM: CDate(Right([Table.Efffrom],2) & "/" & Mid([Table.Efffrom],5,2) & "/" & Left([Table.Efffrom],4))